# What is the importance of loadfactor in rehashing and how to decide the optimal value?

Tags: java, collections

I have come accross articles where the ideal value is givin as .75, but if thats the case it can be fixed but since the developer is given the choice its should not be the case. What are the parameters based on which we decide the value of loadfactor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the parameters based on which we decide the value of loadfactor?

Experimentation. Research.

The actual "ideal" value depends on the data, so you could do your own research with *your* data and potentially find a different "optimal" load factor.

`.75` has been found to be a good *general* load factor, balancing performance vs. memory use, i.e. not wasting memory on empty hashtable buckets, while minimizing the *probability* of hash collisions.

> What is the importance of loadfactor in rehashing?

If the load factor is too low, the hashtable will have a lot of empty buckets, wasting memory.

If the load factor is too high, the probability of hash collisions is too high, reducing performance of hash lookups, since hash collisions means a sequential search is required to find the match (or [balanced tree lookup in Java 8+](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes8.html)).